# Mutt with TMUX, problems with external command

Tags: tmux, mutt

I set up mutt to look up my OS X Contacts, when I compose a new mail, start typing the name and hit `<TAB>` or `<C> - t`.
This works fine, gives me a list with suggestions.

```
set query_command = "contacts -Sf '%eTOKEN%n' '%s' | sed -e 's/TOKEN/\t/g'"
bind editor <Tab> complete-query
bind editor ^T    complete
```

When I ran mutt inside a **tmux** Session, the command does not work. I did try to debug with `mutt -d 2`, but there is no error.

Is tmux blocking some key strokes or preventing mutt from running a shell command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue relates somewhat to this https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-copy-and-paste-with-tmux-on-mac-os-x

If you have homebrew installed, you can do the following to fix your problem:

1. $ `brew install reattach-to-user-namespace`
2. Add this to your tmux config file `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l zsh"` (replace zsh with your shell of choice)

You should be good to go from here!

Comment: Thanks, man. Even if I just did this some os x releases ago (i guess 10.9 or so), it did work now (using macOS 10.12.4)! Thank you.